# How to find overlapping patterns in a regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose I have a string like this `123456789`. Is there any way to find the every possible existing pattern from the given string like this

`1234`, `2345`, `3456`,`4567`, `5678`, `6789` using `regex`

I did this but couldn't figure out the solution:

```
import re
regex = r"[1-9]{4}"
test_string = "123456789"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

this outputs:

```
['1234', '5678']
```

Any help will mean a lot to me, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
\d(?=(\d{3}))
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ya6ezE/2/)

Sample Source ([Run here](http://ideone.com/3r6frg) )

```
import re
regex = r"\d(?=(\d{3}))"
test_str = "123456789"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for match in matches:
 print(match.group()+match.group(1));
```